# How to perform load testing of web application for specific scenarios using JMeter?

Tags: web-applications, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I'm interested in employing JMeter to conduct load testing on my web application. I have a few specific scenarios that I'd like to test, and I have some questions related to these scenarios.

**Load testing for file import in the web application**:
Within this scenario, we have two objectives:

1. Assess the application's performance when a single user imports both single and multiple files.
2. Evaluate the application's performance when multiple users concurrently import single and multiple files.

**Load testing for various functionalities:**
In this particular scenario, our goal is to examine the application's behavior when multiple users simultaneously access different features and functionalities.

I've obtained diverse results, and they are rather intricate to convey to my client. Is there a method to simplify the explanation of the load testing results, allowing my client to make informed decisions regarding infrastructure management more easily?

Answer (score -1):

If you have "complex" test results and you want it to convert them into simple words there are several ways to proceed:

- Take language courses in the nearest school or university
- Hire a freelancer who will do this for you
- Feed the text into a neural-network language model and ask it to provide you a summary

In general creating and running a script is less than 5-10% of the performance testing work, the main job begins when you need to analyze the test results. If your contract ends on collecting the results you can just "convey to my client" and forget.

If you need to perform deeper analysis the "simple" strategy will be different depending on the [performance test types](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-vs-load-testing-vs-stress-testing)

- For [load testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Load_testing) you simply check that metrics like response time or throughput match [NFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) or [SLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement)
- For [stress testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Stress_testing) you need to determine the [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html), i.e. you start with 1 user and gradually increase the load until errors start occurring or response time goes above acceptable limits
- For [scalability testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability_testing) you need to measure the scalability factor and state whether it is proportional and up to which extent
- etc.